# Изменить имя канала quequ

Tags: php, yii2, очередь

Использую yii2 [https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-queue][1]

При добавлении задачи меняю имя канал тогда в таблице DB driver имя канала изменяется но задачи не выполняются

```
Yii::$app->queue->channel = $id;
Yii::$app->queue->push(new Jobs(["id"=>$id,"start"=>$start, "stop"=>$stop]));
```

Вот так

queue/run имя канал

действует по default каналу.

Как изменить имя канала?

Answer (score 1):

А прочесть документацию? зачеем?

> The queue/run command is supported by the File, Db, Redis, Beanstalk, Gearman, AWS SQS drivers. For additional options see driver guide.

Ходим по документации драйверов и там нет такого

Просто сконфигурируйте несколько очередей и в зависимости от условий выбирайте

Comment: Мне нужно чтоб очереди создавались автоматически, в зависимости от количества задач. Ну и спросил потому что в документации нет такого.

Comment: Создать свой класс который это делает

Comment: Если бы я создавал свой класс то этого вопроса тут не было

Comment: Вашу задачу так не решить, вам нужно сделать обертку которая в зависимости от ваших условий будет конструировать очереди + за каждой очередью нужно по разному следить, т.к у разных драйверов свои особенности